# Does a convergent sequence of measurable functions approximate the open set arbitrarily precisely in measure?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\{f_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable functions converging to $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $\forall x \in X. \forall \epsilon >0. \exists n >0. \forall m \ge n. |f(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon$. Recall $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable iff for all $c \in \mathbb{R}$. $f^{-1}((-\infty,c))$ is measurable.
Define $C=f^{-1}((-\infty,c)), C_i=f_i^{-1}((-\infty,c))$.

Is it true that $\forall \epsilon>0.\exists n >0. \forall m \ge n. |\mu(C)-\mu(C_m)|<\epsilon$?

Does a convergent sequence of measurable functions approximate the open set arbitrarily precisely in measure?

Comment: You should edit your title to be something more readable. As of now, it's just a jumble of quantifiers and symbols.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Is it better? I considered the version with symbols more precise and succinct and cannot formulate a much better title in English.

Comment: In which sense does the sequence $(f_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ converge to $f$?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Clarified in the edit.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any assumption on $X$? You talk about open sets, hence I guess there is a topology. If $X$ is a probability space, then what you want is convergence of the cumulative distribution functions. It does not hold at each point, but in any point where the cumulative distribution function is continuous.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo My intuition was telling me that the statement would hold for any general $X$. How could I prove the result for $X=R^n$ and find a simple counterexample for a general $X$? Thank you.